# Elementary OS on a homemade pc build

Tags: hardware

He there! I'm thinking about building my own pc for a while now. I'm using eOS for a week orso, and I really thinking about installing it on my new pc rig to. But because eOS is using a old version of the Linux kernel, my question is: will it run with modern (AMD + NVIDIA, or Itel+NVIDIA) hardware?

-Thaha

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is *it depends*. If you are running Loki, the kernel isn't all that old.

Provided you aren't using anything *really* exotic, Linux typically supports most desktop hardware. I can't remember the last time I had an issue running Linux on a desktop machine - normally issues arise when trying to get it to run on a laptop, where there is poorer support for some chipsets (wireless etc.).

A better way to do this is to use something like [PCPartPicker](http://pcpartpicker.com/) to assemble a potential build which suits your needs, and then post to the [elementary OS subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos) to ask whether your hardware is supported.

Here are some things you might want to avoid:

- 32-bit UEFI firmware
- Older AMD graphics cards

Answer (score 0):

since elementary OS seems to work well on Dell XPS 15 :
[Does elementary OS work on the Dell XPS 15?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5231/does-elementary-os-work-on-the-dell-xps-15?rq=1)
It should work with modern hardware, the XPS 15 having Intel+Nvidia config